# network manager not listing wireless networks

Tags: 14.04

I just installed ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop.
Before I used Ubuntu 13.10 and I had no problem accessing the list of wireless network until I installed this version of Ubuntu.
All of a sudden, the network manager doesn't seem to be picking up any wireless networks.

This is some hardware informations :

## sudo uname -a

```
Linux aimad-Vostro-1015 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:08:14 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

## sudo lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 03)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 03)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 6 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 03)
0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
0f:00.0 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd MMC/SD Host Controller (rev 01)
0f:00.1 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5U2xx (R5U230 / R5U231 / R5U241) [Memory Stick Host Controller] (rev 01)
0f:00.3 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 PCIe IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 01)
```

## sudo ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:ac:6f:5c:bb:2c  
          inet addr:192.168.137.228  Bcast:192.168.137.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::baac:6fff:fe5c:bb2c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7636 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6811 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7458372 (7.4 MB)  TX bytes:856551 (856.5 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:804 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:804 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:61777 (61.7 KB)  TX bytes:61777 (61.7 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:7b:cb:56:ca:f8  
          inet6 addr: fe80::f27b:cbff:fe56:caf8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:2495
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:17 Base address:0xc000
```

How can I solve this problem ?

## Edit :

This is the content of the file `/etc/network/interfaces` :

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: show us the content of /etc/network/interfaces please
make sure to wlan0 is there and correctly configured you may wish to look at the routing table too. Here is a good how-to about networking:
https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html You may also want to look at this:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic#Configure_your_wireless_interface

Comment: @user68186 I already tried all solutions in that post

Comment: @Louis please check the modification I made to my post

Comment: I see you're getting Interrupt 17 on your wlan0. That's the problem. Did you get access to your wifi when you booted up the live usb?

Comment: @AksharPatel no I didn't, because I didn't installed the driver for my wirless card yet.

Answer (score 0):

as of the second URL I gave, add this to /etc/network/interfaces then reboot

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
pre-up  /etc/init.d/wpa.sh start
post-down /etc/init.d/wpa.sh stop
```

Comment: it didn't work :/

Comment: @AimadMajdou Are you able to connect manually using the networking icon in the top right corner?